# iTunes cannot sync photos to the iPhone because your iPhoto library is not yet available

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, photos.app

How to fix this issue and sync iTunes to iPhone correctly?

*OS X Yosemite, iPhoto 9.6.1, iTunes 12.4.3.1; iPhone 5, iOS 9.3.3*

I imported my pictures to iPhoto then tried to sync some unrelated changes to the iPhone through iTunes and got this error message. Restarting iPhoto and iTunes didn't help this time.

---

**Disclaimer:** *I found the solution to this specific issue and I'm using this space to share it with others. Other solutions may be valid on different situations. I remember fixing this once by restarting the Mac.*

---

Here are some links related to this problem with some "heavy weight" solutions I didn't try this time:

1. http://osxdaily.com/2013/06/30/itunes-not-syncing-iphone-ipad-ipod-fix/
2. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6831863
3. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7180697

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting both iPhoto and iTunes a few times and trying it again, eventually I decided to **(1) delete the previously imported photos** on iPhoto:
[image]

Since I didn't want to delete them, **(2) I created a new album with them** and, once back to iTunes, **(3) checked the new album to be sync'ed** back to the iPhone.

It worked!

Comment: It seems like the integration of these systems expects you to take some action after importing pictures (like deleting them) and manage them through iTunes...

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem. This helped me:

- On Mac, terminated the Photos app
- On Mac, terminated the iTunes app
- On iPhone, performed force restart

After that, syncing worked again.